# Set Apache2 to deny SSL connection to vhost without cert

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4

Currently when a host is pointed to it that doesn't have a vhost entry, Apache will try to serve a certificate for the wrong host (which happens to be the first alphabetical).  This is in spite of the fact that the `ServerName` in the vhost conf doesn't match.

If I try to create a default SSL vhost it will fail (apache2 exits) because it doesn't have a cert.

All the certs are LE and installed using certbot.

So my questions are:

1. Why does Apache use that config even thought the `ServerName` is different?
2. How can I set it to simply deny the connection instead of the above?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'create a default SSL vhost', but the default vhost -- which is (by definition) used for connections/requests that don't match any named vhost -- is the _first_ one in the config file and thus already exists. It should not be the first in alpha order by ServerName unless your config _is_ in alpha order by ServerName, which you might do intentionally, or might happen if you use the Debian scheme of individual files per vhost with links in `sites-enabled/$hostname` which are all Include'd in filename=hostname order.

Comment: ... If clients are accessing your server with names you don't own (or don't even know) and can't get cert(s) for, I don't know of any really good solution. Although if only the leftmost label is unknown -- i.e. `able.example.com baker.example.com` etc. -- you could get a wildcard cert for `*.example.com` (supported by LE as of this year) and put it in a new first vhost (which becomes the default) and configure it to give an error response (or error page) for all requests.

Comment: Apache will not use the default vhost because it only listens on port 80, not 443.  They are individual files per vhost, using `sites-enabled`, as certbot wants.  They are not subdomains.